# "more site stats on: Stack Exchange" shows/does nothing

Tags: bug, site-stats

Out of curiosity, while on Writers, I went to check out more stats on the right. I wanted to see how the stats looked on Stack Exchange rather than Area51 so I clicked on the link and was taken to the Sites page ... and nothing.

Thinking it was something to do with Writers.SE from this page I went to the AI.SE (artificial intelligence) via the bubble's Visit Site button. Went to the the same link and got the same result.

The links for both of these sites were [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#writers) and [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#ai) but the url I have in the address bar is [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true#).

Aside from everything after the # being removed I would expect the `expand=true` would open up the bubble but not even this occurs.

Having my Developer Tools open in Chrome 53.0.2785.116 m on Windows 7 does not show any errors in the console and the network tab doesn't show any missing files or anything. I went into Internet Explore 11.0.9600.17239 and Firefox 48.0.2. Both do the same thing.

I assume that the point of these links are to open up their site's bubble on the Site's page which shows the stats like questions, answers and answered % rather than show something totally different but as explained they aren't even opening up the bubble